# Apple Pay Security

Tags: security, apple-pay

When I am walking in the city, I am concerned with what I can do to configure the iPhone so that if it is stolen, it is more difficult or impossible to commit further theft / fraud.

I would like to understand how to secure Apple Pay in my iPhone.

What other steps must be taken to secure Apple Pay, so that the thief is denied access to Apple Pay?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151333/discussion-on-question-by-gatorback-apple-pay-security); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Apple Pay is secured by Face ID/Touch ID and your password. Either of these things generally grant access to Apple Pay.

If your device is stolen, you should use Find My iPhone on iCloud.com to place it in [Lost Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/use-lost-mode-mmfc0f0165/icloud). Doing this will disable Apple Pay until Lost Mode is disabled.

> For applicable devices, payment cards and other services are suspended.

They cannot use your cards unless they know your password. If you ever enter your password in public, it's possible that the passcode was stolen too, so it's a good idea to enable lost mode as soon as possible.

---

While not applicable to using Apple Pay, [Stolen Device Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212510) can prevent people from stealing your phone and then resetting your Apple ID password/stealing your passwords.

Answer (score 4):

I would do precisely what Apple recommends if you lose your device and have Apple Pay enabled - suspend it.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203027

> Your credit, debit, and prepaid cards will be suspended from Apple Pay by your bank, your bank’s authorized service provider, your card issuer, or your issuer's authorized service provider, even if your device is offline and not connected to a cellular or Wi-Fi network.

FindMy apps (device and web) and your Apple ID page on the web both can suspend ApplePay. You can always reenable if you recover or find the device.

---

Just like for any other check, payment card or system, please carefully read your banking agreements. Balance those obligations and agreements with the legal protections you have based on where you bank (and travel). They are what really protect your money more than the physical tokens we carry that grant access to your institutionally stored money. Taking common sense security steps is of course good, but Apple won’t enable Apple Pay without those being in place so you can focus on the actions you control.